# Expected Value of Random Variable Number of Random Variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Given: $N$ ~ $Geo(p_N$) and $X_i$ ~ $Geo(p_X)$
>
> Where $N$ isn't dependent on $X_i$, and all $X_i$s are i.i.d
>
> We define: $Z=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$
>
> 1. Calculate E[Z]
> 2. Calculate var(Z)
> 3. Find m.g.f for Z
> 4. what kind
>    of distribution does Z have?

For 1, I know that $E[Z]=\sum_{i=1}^NE[X_i]=N/{p_x}$

For 2, I know that $var(Z)=\sum_{i=1}^Nvar(X_i)=N(1-P_x)/{P_x^2}$

But, this is true for constant N not random variable... How can I solve this?

Comment: [Wald's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation).

Comment: Basically, write $1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf1_{\{N=n\}}$, expand, and Fubinize.

Comment: Are you familiar with [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable) and [conditional variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $N$ is a random variable, independent of the set of $X_i$ variables, and those $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed, then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Z) &= \mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i) \\[1ex] &=\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^N\mathsf E(X_i\mid N)) \\[1ex] &= \mathsf E(N)~\mathsf E(X_1)\end{align}$$

Comment: The OP says "not dependent", @Surb .  However, if it is dependent, then clearly the nature of the dependency will influence the result.

Comment: @GrahamKemp can you explain why the last equality is true

Comment: @David Try to work it out. It follows since $X_i$s are iid and independent of $N.$

Comment: ... and that expectation is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For a suitable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we have:$$\mathbb Ef(Z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Ef(Z\mid N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Ef\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)P(N=n)$$

Comment: Hi, there is no f here...

Comment: You can do it with the functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ in order to find $\mathbb EZ$ and $\mathbb EZ^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

According to total probability formula,
$$\mathbb E[Z]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb E[Z\mid N=n]\mathbb P\{N=n\}.$$

Because $N$ is independent of the $X_i$'s, $$\mathbb E[Z\mid N=n]=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E[X_i]=np_X.$$

Comment: your answer is different compared to the other answer

Comment: BTW the solution is wrong, you claim that E[Z] is $\infty$...

Comment: @David Not at all... where did you see that I claim that $\mathbb E[Z]=\infty $ ? At the end you gen $\mathbb E[Z]=\mathbb E[N]\mathbb E[X_1]$, which is correct ;-)